# Robots.txt syntax not understood

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

I submitted my robots.txt file ages ago to Google and it is still giving me a syntax not understood for the first line.

After Googling the most common problem is Google adding a '?' at the start of the line but it isnt doing that to me.

the url to the robots.txt is

www.leisurepursuits.co.uk/robots.txt

The error is:

Line 1: User-agent: *                          Syntax not understood

Comment: I thought it was a great question....thanks Lex.  Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This error shows because the expected robots.txt file format is plain text encoded in UTF-8. The file consists of records (lines) separated by CR, CR/LF or LF.

If a character encoding is not a subset of UTF-8, then your robots.txt files is being parsed incorrectly.

First check your robots.txt url in http://www.asymptoticdesign.co.uk/cgi-bin/check-url.pl by selecting the second option “view source” and see that it responds successfully or not.

Now upload your robots.txt file again. It will not show error as shown previously.

Comment: Links no longer works.
http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/42 fixes for me

Comment: I originally created the robots.txt file through VS2013, which was my issue.  After reading this post, I opened in Notepad, saved, and then uploaded again and it worked.

Comment: Throwing this in here but you can right-click on the text file in solution explorer, "open with" > "source code text with encoding" > choose "western european (windows)" and whala!  You will see the extraneous characters in the beginning.